# Parse, query to find games of one user

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In parse i have a "Game" class with array pointer column called "Players". I want to get games that contain `[PFUser currentUser]` in arrayKey called "Players", always this column stored a three players array.

I tried some query, i couldn't get success.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
[query whereKey:@"Players" containsAllObjectsInArray:@[[PFUser currentUser]]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) 
{...}];
```

Also tried.

```
[query whereKey:@"Players" containsAllObjectsInArray:@[[PFUser currentUser].objectId]];
```

I'm sure already stored a Game with current User inside.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Game"];
[query whereKey:@"Players" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) 
{...}];
```

If you run `equalTo` on an array key, it checks to see if the value is in the array.

Make sure to check that you stored a pointer to the user, and not their objectId.  If you're storing id's instead, do `equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];`

Comment: Have you checked your data browser to make sure games are saving properly?

Comment: You was right. Sorry, My fault was that I was not storing the current user in the array of players.